# HQL make joins with 2 tables that depends on one root table with one SQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have 3 tables
tableA has references to tableB.id and tableC.id

So in my entity:

```
class TableA{

  @OneToMany
  public TableB getTableB(){}

  @OneToMany
  public TableC getTableC(){}

}
```

So I need to select all records from tableA with prefetched tableB and C. I write HQL:

```
select a from TableA a inner join a.tableB inner join a.tableC
```

But then I see a huge load of subselects in logs. So it selects a record from tableA and then runs a sparate select for fetching table Ab and C. Why? FectchMode.JOIN didn't help. I need a one monolithic SQL and I can run it successfully in DB tool. How to do that in HQL?

Comment: What JPA implementation are you using? Are you using the lazy load fetch type? have you check the use of "JOIN FETCH" in the HQL?

Comment: This code makes no sense. A OneToMany must annotate a collection. An inner join doesn't pre-fetch. A **left join fetch** does that. Read the documentation. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching